# Asus G53S keyboard backlight

Tags: linux, debian, keyboard, keyboard-backlight

I have troubles enabling keyboard backlight in Asus G53SW-XR1 (2.6.39-2 kernel) with modules:

```
$ lsmod | grep asus 
asus_nb_wmi            12393  0 
asus_wmi               18488  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          12760  1 asus_wmi
pci_hotplug            30807  1 asus_wmi
wmi                    13202  1 asus_wmi
rfkill                 19014  5 asus_wmi,bluetooth,cfg80211
```

The lights light up just after turning on the laptop (even before grub) but then go dark. When I press the button I get log messages:

```
Nov 18 16:14:36 grendl kernel: [  383.513969] keyboard: can't emulate rawmode for keycode 240
Nov 18 16:14:36 grendl kernel: [  383.513992] keyboard: can't emulate rawmode for keycode 240
Nov 18 16:14:36 grendl kernel: [  383.514002] asus_wmi: Unknown key b7 pressed
```